# MVC open DataReader error when selecting from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting the following error when I am to trying to populate a variable by selecting from the database:

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first."

```
            //Admin Venue Partial View
            public ActionResult AdminVenuesTablePartialView()
            {
                VenueTownViewModel vt = new VenueTownViewModel();
                List<VenueTownViewModel> model = new List<VenueTownViewModel>();

                foreach (var venue in db.Venues)
                {
                    vt.VenueID = venue.VenueID;
                    vt.VenueName = venue.VenueName;
                    vt.VenueTown = db.Towns.Find(venue.TownID).Town;
                    vt.VenueActive = venue.VenueActive;

                    model.Add(vt);                
                }

                return PartialView("_AdminVenues", model.OrderBy(v => v.VenueName).ToList());
            }
```

Comment: The issue is cause by your `vt.VenueTown = db.Towns.Find(venue.TownID).Town;` Your making another database call while your reading `Venues`. If you models are set up correctly with FK relationships, there is no need to that call.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense I'll the make the changes to the model, thanks Stephen!